# Grabbing the text out of a textblock on another page

Tags: c#, wpf

Using the Minimal UI package here, http://mui.codeplex.com/ I'm using a listview and am trying to figure out how to grab the text out of one page's entry and use it in another page. Kind of like

```
string NewAlert = Textblock1.Text;
```

but across pages.
If I need anymore information, please tell me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the pages on separate threads ?
You can make a static function on page A
That will receive the text or whatever, 
And in page B , whenever your get the event 
You can send you text to that function. 
Don't forget to include.

Or if you want to get that text as event you have to send to page A the event (windows message) 
You can do that with delegate.

Comment: Alright; tried it with the static functions and got it to work. Thanks.